# What is the proper way to add an image to Morea markdown-formatted page?

Tags: morea-framework

I am trying to add an image to the landing home page. For this, I have created a folder `assets` within `master/src/morea` and placed the image there.

Then, I have added a line into `home.md`:

```
![GrammarViz 2.0 screenshot](/morea/assets/screen-front.png "GrammarViz 2.0 screenshot")
```

The problem is that I see the image locally (`http://localhost:4000/morea/assets/screen-front.png`), but it had not appeared at github, because of the erroneous URL that has "morea" instead of my repository name:`http://seninp.github.io/morea/assets/screen-front.png`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that image URLs must be relative URLs in Morea.   So, the fix is to simply remove the leading slash:

```
![GrammarViz 2.0 screenshot](morea/assets/screen-front.png "GrammarViz 2.0 screenshot")
```

Take a look at the [ICS311s14 site](http://philipmjohnson.github.io/ics311s14/index.html) for a working example.