# How do I add images to markdown pages in the Morea framework?

Tags: morea-framework

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410945/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-an-image-to-morea-markdown-formatted-page) answer, and can confirm it works for me, but only on the `home.md` file. If I add images to any other markdown file, they fail to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't have enough context yet to help.  For images, I use an include file that inserts the following HTML into the markdown file.  You can trying using this HTML and see if it works:

```
<div class="center-block">
  <div class="img-responsive">
    <a href="FILE.PNG"><img width="400px" src="FILE.PNG"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Replace FILE.PNG by the image.  I would start by putting it in the same directory and then if that works, you can move it to a relative location.

Comment: My fault. [Here](http://bruab.github.io/morea_test/index.html) is a minimal example of what I'm talking about. The image displays on the home page, but not on this [module page](http://bruab.github.io/morea_test/modules/foo/).  ([Source code](https://github.com/bruab/morea_test))

Comment: Just created a [pull request](https://github.com/bruab/morea_test/pull/1) on your example repo. Basically, you can use a relative link to move out of modules/foo/ directory and into morea/.